# How to deploy solution with multiple web projects with VSTS?

Tags: asp.net, tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I have a solution with multiple web-projects and many class libraries.
I want to deploy web-projects to my own VM with installed deployment agents.
Should I create for every web-project separate its own Build and Release Definitions, right?

Comment: That can't be answered by us. You need to think about the pros/cons of each approach and then decide what works best for you.

Comment: @mason Is it possible to deploy all web-projects from the solution for one build? How can I do it?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Asking how is too broad: you need to read up on how to perform builds and releases in VSTS. There's documentation out there, it's up to you to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, creating separate Build and Release definition for each web project works. But if you want to use one build & release definition, it also can be achieved, and there are many ways.

For example, if you want to use each project artifact, you could use individual project files in the solution to build in Build definition. Or you could copy the file you need for one project in Release definition, etc. In a word, it depends on how do you want to achieve your requirement.